# Exporting mySQL data to Excel sheet with Dates formate YYYY-mm-dd

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel

I am exporting data from a MySQL database into an Excel sheet using PHP. Everything works fine, but date field data is automatically converted from `YYYY-mm-dd` to `dd-mm-YYYY` in Excel sheet.

PHP Code:

```js
$results = mysql_query("SELECT name,contact,reg_date FROM reg");
 
$headerDisplayed = false;
 
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    // Add a header row if it hasn't been added yet
    if ( !$headerDisplayed ) {
        // Use the keys from $data as the titles
        fputcsv($fh,$data);
        $headerDisplayed = true;
    }
 
    // Put the data into the stream
    fputcsv($fh, $data);
}
```

DB table
[image]

Output in Excel:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: "mysql_query" ??? That hasn't been supported for years.

Comment: So what is supported ?

Comment: I don't think this is related to your code, more likely it is the way Excel displays dates by default.

Comment: What happens if you select your date column in Excel and change the date format to the format you want? Does that work and display the dates appropriately?

Comment: @shreya . . . mysqli_:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.

Comment: @Matt Gibson I am trying to change date format which is I want but Its display as it is,Changes not reflated

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you **shouldn't** use mysql_query at all, please use http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. The MySQL module had a lot of flaws and security vulnerabilities.

Now to answer your question:

Before putting your date in the fputcsv function you can transform it to your liking by using the [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), this is part of PHP itself.

What you can do is the following:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['date']);
$data['date'] = $date->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Edit: I misunderstood the question, my apologies. **I think this is related to your Excel settings based on your system language.** I'll keep this answer here just in case someone does stumble upon it :)